# Laravel 5 Modular route files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and the modular package:
https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular

I created an admin modul with the following route file:

```
Route::group(array('module' => 'Admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'), function() {

Route::get('admin/test', 'AdminController@createTestView');

});
```

When I call http://localhost/admin/test it redirects me to the test view.
When I call http://localhost/admin/test2 it redirects me to my 404.blade.php file which I create for pages which does not exist anymore.

When I call http://localhost/admin I get the following error message in the browser:
"The requested resource /Site was not found on this server."

Any ideas why it does not redirect to the 404.blade.php site?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a route for `admin/test2`, that's why you're getting 404 error. If you want to pass an ID to your controller, you should create route with a parameter:
`admin/test{id}`

**UPDATE:**

```
Route::group(array('module' => 'Admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'), function() {

    Route::get('admin/{someParam}', 'AdminController@createTestView');

});
```

Then in a `createTestView` action:

```
public function createTestView($someParam){
    dd($someParam); // Shows you contents of $someParam
}
```

Comment: I would like that with the URL http://localhost/admin I get a 404.But instead I just get the error message